# Nuxt and Vue deploy in same domain

Tags: node.js, vue.js, deployment, nuxt.js, vue-cli

I have nuxt project and vue-cli project. nuxt is my main project. I deployed nuxt in root directory of my server using proxy pass at localhost:3000

```
nuxt ----> www.example.com
```

I want to deploy vue-cli project in [www.example.com/portal](http://www.example.com/portal)

```
vue-cli ----> www.example.com/portal
```

But the routes of the vue project like [www.example.com/portal/login](http://www.example.com/portal/login) always goes to nuxt project.
Is there any solution to resolve that issue? Can I deploy nuxt without using prox pass?

Comment: Using NGINX as a reverse proxy  https://ru.nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/nginx-proxy/

Comment: @OleksiiZelenko I am using apache server